# Why is only 'else' part getting executed, even if 'if' is true?

Tags: java, android

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.santosh.sampleapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity
{
    EditText password_field;
    TextView tv_err;
    Button login;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        password_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        tv_err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_err);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        final String password = password_field.getText().toString();


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (password.equals("password")) {
                        tv_err.setText("good pass");
                    } else {
                        tv_err.setText("wrong pass");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    tv_err.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Even if I type `password` at the textview, it shows me a `wrong pass` message.

Here is my *src/layout/main.xml* if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText android:id="@+id/password_field"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button android:id="@+id/login"
    android:text="@string/get_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tw_err"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: get password_field value from login button click listener

Comment: Because, as you declared password outside your listener, it has not current value but it's initial value.

Comment: you get password string from password_field before click event on login button. you should getText when onClick event happen

Comment: First Check value of `password.equals("password")`                         Use Log.i("**************", "this is passqord check"+password.equals("password")); and check value of it.

Comment: I don't know why is this getting downvoted. If not here, then where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `password` is not updated. It contains the original value. Update like so:

```
if (password_field.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
```

BTW: keep on using the `final` keyword as much as possible! Minimize the mutable state in your app and you'll be a happy man.

Comment: It has to be `password_field.getText().toString()` in the 'if' to compare it dude..

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I couldn't run the code in head correctly. :)

Comment: I hope you like your new reputation. Keep on!

Answer (score 6):

Get the password from TextView inside onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        final String password = password_field.getText().toString();
        if (password.equals("password")) {
            tv_err.setText("good pass");
        } else {
            tv_err.setText("wrong pass");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv_err.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

becuase you are getting your Password string onCreate() method..Which will be not updated.. So you to find your Password value after click event of button.....

So put this line

```
final String password = password_field.getText().toString();
```

after click on button...

Answer (score 1):

change your Login button click listener as below:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                 final String strPassword=password_field.getText().toString(); 
                    if (TextUtils.equals(strPassword, "password")) {
                        tv_err.setText("good pass");
                    } else {
                        tv_err.setText("wrong pass");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    tv_err.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the EditText into the String variable inside the Click Listener.

Try out as below:

> ```
>  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>           String password = password_field.getText().toString();
>             try {
>                 if (password.equals("password")) {
>                     tv_err.setText("good pass");
>                 } else {
>                     tv_err.setText("wrong pass");
>                 }
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 tv_err.setText(e.toString());
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The password string not updated when click login button, remove the line:

```
final String password = password_field.getText().toString();
```

Check the string inside `onClick` listener:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (password_field.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
                    tv_err.setText("good pass");
                } else {
                    tv_err.setText("wrong pass");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tv_err.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

and no need to use `String password = password_field.getText().toString();`
its allocate memory for string, so directly check:

```
if (password_field.getText().toString().equals("password"))
```